# Parse POCO list of objects to javascript using WebMethod

Tags: javascript, c#, webmethod

I have a get ajax call:

```
function TraerInstructivos() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Instructivo/Instructivos.aspx") %>' + '/TraerInstructivos',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {

            $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                alert(item.DescripcionVideo);
                alert(item.DireccionVideo);
            });
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
};
```

That calls the following webmethod in my aspx:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static List<InstructivoDTO> TraerInstructivos()
{
    try
    {
        return Controles_Instructivo_Instructivos.TraerInstructivos();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

}
```

That calls a piece of code in my ascx:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static List<InstructivoDTO> TraerInstructivos()
{
    List<InstructivoDTO> lstResponse = new List<InstructivoDTO>();

    WC.InstructivoDTOResp response = new WC.InstructivoDTOResp() { ListaDeInstructivos = new WC.ListaDeInstructivos() };

    //Traigo los instructivos
    WC.InstructivoDTOReq request = new WC.InstructivoDTOReq()
    {
        TipoOperacion = WC.Accion.Consultar,
        Operacion = Constantes.Consultas.Instructivos.TRAER_INSTRUCTIVOS_WEB_COMERCIO,
        ListaDeInstructivos = new WC.ListaDeInstructivos()
    };

    using (WC.FacturaClient fc = new WC.FacturaClient())
    {
        response = fc.InstructivosEjecutar(request);
    }

    foreach (var i in response.ListaDeInstructivos)
    {
        lstResponse.Add(new InstructivoDTO()
            {
                DescripcionVideo = i.DescripcionVideo,
                DireccionVideo = i.DireccionVideo,
                EsBackOffice = i.EsBackOffice
            });

    }

    return lstResponse;
}
```

That returns a list of POCO objects or DTOs, simple ones really, it has 3 properties, 2 of them of type string, the other one boolean.

In the alert function in my ajax call I see that I receive 'undefined' as result.

Am I missing something? I tried `stringify`, `JSON.Parse(response.d)` which says 'invalid character'.

***EDIT:***

Thanks to the response of  HaukurHaf I changed the for loop inside my jquery, it seems that, when I was doing some tests I changed it, so my Ajax is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        TraerInstructivos();
    });

    function TraerInstructivos() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Instructivo/Instructivos.aspx") %>' + '/TraerInstructivos',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {

                $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                    alert(item.DescripcionVideo);
                    alert(item.DireccionVideo);
                });
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    };

</script>
```

Still Undefined, this is the interesting part, if I put a console.log instead of the alert to my whole object, I can see it with the values I put on my table:

[image]

Comment: the name of the parameter to the callback function is **response**, but you are trying to foreach over **result** which is undefined..

Comment: Thanks HaukurHaf, I made the corresponding Edit to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

It seems I was lacking the other half of the whole solution. The reason it was not working, it's because Im saying Im returning a Json object to the ajax call, but instead Im returning the objects without serializing them. So the code right now looks like this:

**ASPX:**

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string TraerInstructivos()
{
    try
    {
        List<InstructivoDTO> response = Controles_Instructivo_Instructivos.TraerInstructivos();
        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(response);
        return json;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

}
```

**AJAX Call:**

```
function TraerInstructivos() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Instructivo/Instructivos.aspx") %>' + '/TraerInstructivos',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var res = JSON.parse(response.d);
            $.each(res, function (i, item) {
               alert(item.DescripcionVideo);
            });
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
};
```